# How to test expansion file without publishing the application on android market

Tags: android

I need to test expansion file without publishing application on android market.
I tried to google but didn't find any way to do this.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you looking for the term "sandboxing" ?

Comment: No, I am looking for android APK Expansion File[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html). I didn't able to find from google that how to test this without publishing app on android market. Is is possible to test without publishing application.?

Comment: For better understanding check my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933508/problems-testing-apk-expansion-library/12577825#12577825

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had search a lot and finally comes to the conclusion that Android doesn't have such kind of facility. :(

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have to do it manually. Check the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can test the expansion file functionality without publishing your application on Android PlayStore using below instructions:

> Because your application must sometimes manually download the expansion files when it first opens, it's important that you test this process to be sure your application can successfully query for the URLs, download the files, and save them to the device.
>
> To test your application's implementation of the manual download procedure, you must upload your application to Google Play as a "draft" to make your expansion files available for download:
>
> 1. Upload your APK and corresponding expansion files using the Google Play Developer Console.
> 2. Fill in the necessary application details (title, screenshots, etc.). You can come back and finalize these details before publishing your application.
> 3. Click the Save button. Do not click Publish. This saves the application as a draft, such that your application is not published for Google Play users, but the expansion files are available for you to test the download process. Install the application on your test device using the Eclipse tools or adb.
> 4. Launch the app.
>
> If everything works as expected, your application should begin downloading the expansion files as soon as the main activity starts.

REFERENCE LINK : [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#TestingReading)

Answer (score 2):

> Update for those reading this post, you now have to publish your apk
>   in alpha or beta mode before the expansion files will work and you can
>   test your app. I have also included some info that may come in handy to.

**NOTE 1**

You can't use draft anymore as the link to get the expansion file won't be active yet. You have to upload a version to Alpha or Beta first with expansion file. (adding an expansion file is only possible from the second apk you upload and up) So make sure you see the apk expansion file listed when you click the details in the developer publish section under APK.

**NOTE 2**

If you are using android studio and want to make use of the downloader library don't just copy the package name and java files into your own app src directory. Import the downloader library in eclipse and choose export => gradle build files. Afterwards you can import the library as a module in android studio.

**NOTE 3**

Not sure of this but I also think it's neccesary to download the app atleast once through the play store and have access to it with the account on your test device. So if you are working with alpha create a google+ test group and add yourself or other test devices to it.