# Service Intent must be explicit: Intent

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an app some time now in which I call a service through a broadcast receiver (MyStartupIntentReceiver). The code in the broadcast receiver in order to call the service is:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("com.duk3r.eortologio2.MyService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

The problem is that in Android 5.0 Lollipop I get the following error (in previous versions of Android, everything works ok):

```
Unable to start receiver com.duk3r.eortologio2.MyStartupIntentReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.duk3r.eortologio2.MyService }
```

What do I have to change in order for the service to be declared as explicit and start normally? Tried some answers in other similar threads but although i got rid of the message, the service wouldn't start.

Comment: is this a service in your app?

Comment: yes the package com.duk3r.eortologio2 is my app.

Comment: Only have an `<intent-filter>` on a component when you want third-party apps to communicate with that component. You seem to have fallen into the trap of assuming that you need an `<intent-filter>` for everything -- in reality, you infrequently need an `<intent-filter>`. An explicit `Intent` is when you designate the component to talk to in the `Intent` itself, usually using the constructor that takes a Java `Class` object as the second parameter. That, rather than implicit `Intent`s and `<intent-filter>`s, are what you should use for components local to your app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android L (API 21) - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183164/android-l-api-21-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

any intent you make to a service, activity etc. in your app should always follow this format

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

or

```
Intent bi = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
bi.setPackage("com.android.vending");
```

implicit intents (what you have in your code currently) are considered a security risk

Comment: What if I need to `bindService`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky then you have to manually set the package which makes it explicit

Comment: If you want to get the package dynamically, use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

Comment: Beautiful answer. This indeed eliminated my "Service Intent must be explicit" error. But now I am getting *"Your version of Market may be out of date. You can continue to use this app but you won't be able to make purchases."* How do I solve this?

Comment: Why may I not call the default constructor with no arguments: `Intent i = new Intent();` It doesn't seem like that constructor is deprecated why shouldn't I be using it?  Perhaps I just need to be sure to set BOTH a class AND a context.  But what if my intent has a name like `i.setAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");` but is not invoked by using a class definition just a string?  Why MUST I do it your way instead?

Answer (score 35):

Set your `packageName` works.

```
intent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: This works great and doesn't pigeon hole me away from using default constructors with no arguments.  Some days I like to think non-default constructors (ie: constructs which DO have any arguments at all) are an anti-pattern...

Answer (score 6):

Convert implicit intent to explicit intent then fire start service.

```
        Intent implicitIntent = new Intent();
        implicitIntent.setAction("com.duk3r.eortologio2.MyService");
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent explicitIntent = convertImplicitIntentToExplicitIntent(implicitIntent, context);
        if(explicitIntent != null){
            context.startService(explicitIntent);
            }


    public static Intent convertImplicitIntentToExplicitIntent(Intent implicitIntent, Context context) {
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = pm.queryIntentServices(implicitIntent, 0);

            if (resolveInfoList == null || resolveInfoList.size() != 1) {
                return null;
            }
            ResolveInfo serviceInfo = resolveInfoList.get(0);
            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(serviceInfo.serviceInfo.packageName, serviceInfo.serviceInfo.name);
            Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(implicitIntent);
            explicitIntent.setComponent(component);
            return explicitIntent;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it works for me. Here **MonitoringService** is my service class. I have two action, which indicate service to stop or start. I send that value from my **broadcast receiver**  depend on **AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED**.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED.equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
         boolean isOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("state", false);
         String serviceAction = isOn? MonitoringService.StopAction : MonitoringService.StartAction;
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MonitoringService.class);
         serviceIntent.setAction(serviceAction);
         context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I add following code to trigger my broadcast receiver named: **ManageLocationListenerReceiver**.

```
<receiver
     android:name=".ManageLocationListenerReceiver"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score -1):

I improved the answer of Shahidul to remove the context dependency:

```
public class ServiceUtils {
    public static void startService(String intentUri) {
        Intent implicitIntent = new Intent();
        implicitIntent.setAction(intentUri);
        Context context = SuperApplication.getContext();
        Intent explicitIntent = convertImplicitIntentToExplicitIntent(implicitIntent, context);
        if(explicitIntent != null){
            context.startService(explicitIntent);
        }
    }

    private static Intent convertImplicitIntentToExplicitIntent(Intent implicitIntent, Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = pm.queryIntentServices(implicitIntent, 0);

        if (resolveInfoList == null || resolveInfoList.size() != 1) {
            return null;
        }
        ResolveInfo serviceInfo = resolveInfoList.get(0);
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(serviceInfo.serviceInfo.packageName, serviceInfo.serviceInfo.name);
        Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(implicitIntent);
        explicitIntent.setComponent(component);
        return explicitIntent;
    }
}
```

Inside the SuperApplication class:

```
public class SuperApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApp instance;

    public static SuperApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
        // or return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

In your manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.app.SuperApplication "
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    .......
    <activity
        ......
```

And then, just call:

```
ServiceUtils.startService("com.myservice");
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to call a global single instance class to get context. Instead, expose this dependency please.

Comment: How you can call the application context if the ServiceUtils is outside of the activity? Can you provide some example?

Comment: ServiceUtils is a utility, thus, it's not necessary to depend on a concret Application class such as SuperApplication. It's the responsibility of the caller of startService method to provide a context. For convenience, it's possible to inject the Application to be used every where in the application. But as you may already find, it's not a good idea to allow the method to be called "every where". We'd better create classes with only single (set of) responsibility and avoid unnecessary dependency. This way, it's unit-testable and the code is clean.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will not remove that answer to the others learn more about this too.

Comment: You can use the benefit of extension functions to provide context, like this: `fun Context.startService(s: String)` which can be called from within any context wrappers such as activities or services