# Google Play Pre-Launch Report

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

I recently uploaded my app to the Play but got this pre-launch report indicating that of the thirteen devices tested, my app runs well on eight and doesn't run on five. Upon detail analysis, I realized that all the five run `Android 5.0 and 5.1`. I build the app in android studio.

This is the report I get. How do I solve this?

```
Device(s) with issues
Google Nexus 7 (flo) - Android 5.0
Google Nexus 9 (flounder) - Android 5.0
Google Nexus 5 (hammerhead) - Android 5.1
Google Nexus 4 (mako) - Android 5.1
Samsung Galaxy S6 (zeroflte) - Android 5.1

Exceptions
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techafriq.ubiserve/com.techafriq.ubiserve.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techafriq.ubiserve/com.techafriq.ubiserve.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techafriq.ubiserve/com.techafriq.ubiserve.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techafriq.ubiserve/com.techafriq.ubiserve.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techafriq.ubiserve/com.techafriq.ubiserve.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842430/service-intent-must-be-explicit-intent

Comment: @Ashwani not a direct duplicate, but you're indeed pointing to the solution.

Comment: agree but it has the solution so i pointed it out..:)