# Where are Pre-launch Report Warning Details

Tags: android, google-play-console

Silly question, but where are the warnings detailed for Pre-launch Reports? I have some Warnings but can't find details. This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438827/google-play-pre-launch-report) shows details the user was able to get, but I don't know how.

[image]

UPDATE:

Accessibility tab looks like this (but looked similar on older APKs when Overview showed 0 Warnings):

[image]

[image]

UPDATE 2:

I've got it down to 0 Warnings. They were Accessibility based:

- two EditText views with height="wrap_content" - changed to height="48dp"
- An ImageView which was clickable but unlabelled

I'm reverting to a clickable image as it provides a second convenient/intuitive means of loading an image over the also included Button.

Didn't change anything about the Minor issues and that has risen to 4 now due to TalkBack issue now in 4 devices, was just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the different tabs on the top to view the warnings in different categories (e.g. Performance, Accessibility, etc...) or scroll down to the major category summaries (Crashes, Performance, Security) and click the arrow to expand the Results section to see what the warning is.

EDIT: Also note that Google Play Developer Console has been rather flaky lately (regular un-reproducable warnings about API 28 (Android P) devices, and a bunch of new accessibility checks showing up on the main page that may or may not be relevant)

[image: Screenshot from console]

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I've been through the different tabs and can't see warnings. There are lots (>21) associated with accessibility. My app went from 0 warnings to 21 warnings in one step. Looking at those older APKs they also had lots of Accessibility warnings, but 0 warnings in Overview.

Comment: Ah OK, I do see lots of stuff on the Accessibility page Content labelling: 2 issues were identified /!\ 35 examples [!] 1 example. Touch target size: 2 issues were identified.

Comment: So is it that those previously wouldn't have counted against the overview whereas they now do (as of a couple of days ago). Can you re-run a pre-launch report on an older APK to check?

Comment: Thank you Tyler, it's worrying as it's my first app and it was at 0 and 21 seems a big step up from that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176523/discussion-between-tyler-v-and-user1228123).