# Xamarin.Android: starting a new intent

Tags: xamarin.android

I was targeting android 4.4 and was starting a service like this

```
start.Click += delegate {
    StartService(new Intent("com.xamarin.LocationService"));
    start.Enabled = false;
    stop.Enabled = true;
};
```

and it all worked fine. Now I am targeting 6.0 and find from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842430/service-intent-must-be-explicit-intent) that this isn't secure, and I should do this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

but I cannot work out what the arguments for 'new Intent()' should be. The class name is 'LocationActivity' but if I do this

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(LocationActivity));
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

it compiles OK but the service doesn't actually start.

The marked answer in that thread also suggests this

```
Intent bi = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
bi.setPackage("com.android.vending");
```

but if I try that I find that 'Intent does not contain a  definition for setPackage'.

So, can someone help me with a solution here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to start an activity you need to use StartActivity and not StartService
Then use this but change from StartService to StartActivity.

From

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(LocationActivity));
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

To

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(LocationActivity));
context.StartActivity(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: Ah! I _do_ want to start a  service, not an activity. So my argument should the type of the service I want to start, _not_ the type of the activity it's being started from!. So your answer led me indirectly to the solution: `new Intent(this, typeof(LocationService))`