# Error Android app when change targetSDKVersion from 19 to 26

Tags: java, android, targetsdkversion

can anyone help my problem?

My previous android application used targetSdkVersion: 19 then I changed to 26, but there was a problem like the following.

[**This LogCat**](https://prnt.sc/ken3ul)

**This is the snippet of the MusicManager.java code**

```
  private static Intent musicIntent = new Intent("onet.BGMUSIC");

public void play() {
    if (isBgMisicEnabled()) {
        musicIntent.putExtra("bgmusic", bgMusicRes);
        ctx.startService(musicIntent);
    }
}

public void stop() {
    ctx.stopService(musicIntent);
}
```

**This is the snippet of the BaseActivity.java code**

```
    public static MusicManager musicMgr = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initMusic();
}

private void initMusic() {
    if (musicMgr == null) {
        musicMgr = new MusicManager(this);
    }
    playMusic();
}

protected void playMusic() {
    if (musicMgr != null) {
        musicMgr.play();
    }
}

protected void stopMusic() {
    if (musicMgr != null) {
        musicMgr.stop();
    }
}
```

**This is the snippet of the WelcomeActivity.java code**

```
    @Override
protected void playMusic() {
    if (musicMgr != null) {
        musicMgr.setBgMusicRes(R.raw.welcomebg);
        musicMgr.play();
    }
}


private void initMusicSetting() {
    ivMusic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.music);
    setGameMusic();
    if (musicMgr != null) {
        musicMgr.setBgMisicEnabled(LevelCfg.globalCfg.isGameBgMusic());
    }
}
```

**This is the snippet of the Manifest.xml code**

```
        <service
        android:name="onet.sound.MusicService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="onet.BGMUSIC" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must set the package beforehand like :

```
if (isBgMisicEnabled()) {
    musicIntent.setPackage("onet")
    musicIntent.putExtra("bgmusic", bgMusicRes);
    ctx.startService(musicIntent);
}
```

or create the intent like:

```
Intent musicIntent= new Intent(ctx, MusicService.class);
```

as illustrated here: [Service Intent must be explicit: Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842430/service-intent-must-be-explicit-intent)

Comment: I have tried and succeeded, thank you very much for your help. I salute your knowledge :)

if I can know why only change the target SDKVersion from 19 to 26, an error appears (the app becomes force close)?

Comment: I think this was introduced between 19 and 26 as security feature. Glad I could help, please don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: What you did was an implicit intent, by setting the package you make it explicit, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

**new Intent(this, BGMUSIC.class)**

instead of

**new Intent("onet.BGMUSIC")**

Implicit intents are not preferred in the latest versions because of security risk. Hence you should be using class names

Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);