# Api level 21 (Lollipop) - Service Intent must be explicit in Youtube SDK

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }"

Comment: Post Code. Post Entire Stacktrace From Logcat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google In-App billing, IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit, after upgrading to Android L Dev Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480069/google-in-app-billing-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be-explicit)

Comment: @JaredBurrows i agree with u...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android L (API 21) - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183164/android-l-api-21-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be)

Answer (score 3):

Update your Youtube API to 1.2.1...

Here is download link

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

just for anyone in the future reading this

i had this youtube service intent problem too

i stupidly had the youtube jar in the libs folder AND was compiling youtube in the gradle

removing from the gradle fixed it