# Service Intent must be explicit

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to use service for a background music.

```
package com.example.neotavraham;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class PlayMusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
  public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.neotavraham.PLAY";
  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
      mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yedid_nefesh);
      mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
      mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
    }
    return flags;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I call it from the `MainActivity` with the line: `startService(new Intent(PlayMusicService.ACTION_PLAY));`

and of course I added an intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.neotavraham.PLAY"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I was looking for a fine solution in the internet but couldn't find one...what should I do?

Comment: so what is the problem with above? what is not working?

Comment: @SMR,Oops,i forgat to add the error, although i wrote it in the title, the app crashes and the error is "Service Intent must be explicit"

Comment: What did you name your service in the manifest? Please show us that part.

Comment: how did you start the service ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android L (API 21) - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183164/android-l-api-21-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity do the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,PlayMusicService.class);
i.putExtra("action","com.example.neotavraham.PLAY");
startService(i);
```

In your service do the following:

```
package com.example.neotavraham;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class PlayMusicService extends Service  {
  public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.neotavraham.PLAY";
  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
      mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yedid_nefesh);
      mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
    return flags;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

In your manifiest do the following:

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.neotavraham.PlayMusicService"
           />
```

This is the perfect code for your app. Hope this will work finally....

Comment: It works!, thank you very much! one last thing, i wan't to process this on another thread so im trying to use prepareAsync() as shown in my code, but it gives "java.lang.IllegalStateException" error

Comment: Since service is already in background you dont need to work with another thread...

Answer (score 2):

Please call the service from intent and set the action of that intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,PlayMusicService.class);
i.setAction("com.example.neotavraham.PLAY");
startService(i);
```

This code will work.

**Background service for start media player**

```
package com.example.neotavraham;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class PlayMusicService extends Service  {
  public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.neotavraham.PLAY";
  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {

      mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
    return flags;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: ok the error is gone but the music doesn't start, why is that?

Comment: Everything looking good what error are u getting?? Also please use debugger to check where the problem is?

Comment: Please check my edited answer and try to use the code. It must work

Comment: tried it,didn't work, the weird thing is that it doesn't even get to the if statement inside onStartCommand method, i checked it with logcat

Comment: What u are getting in intent.getAction()?

Comment: actually i put the line "Log.d("Prepare media player: ",intent.getAction());" before the if statement and it prints nothing...

Comment: Remove if statement then check whether media player code working??

Comment: U can do one more thing you can send string through putExtra from activity to service

Comment: I don't get it, i removed the if statement, i started the service with the same lines you give here, but nothing is happed and no log messages has been written...it's like, the onStartCommand method is not even being called

Comment: I added another answer . Please do the same as i did in answer. Your code will run perfect...