# Android background service on Android 5 can't restart

Tags: android, xamarin, background-service

I make a non-stop background service for Android app, my solution is to send a broadcast to the registered receiver on the method OnTaskRemoved  :

[image: Background Service]

and start the service again on the received:
[image: Broadcast Receiver]

But it only works on Android 6 and 7, not on 5 and 5.1.
Anyone knows how to deal with it, please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: please share your code as text instead of this images so people could copy and debug it easily.

Comment: You need to check the if statement. Which line of the code make the service do not restart?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT you can check the OnTaskRemoved function, I SendBroadcast but it doesn't work, the service still be stopped

Comment: Try to start the service explicitely. Do something in OnTaskRemoved function like what you do in OnReceive method. Code: `Intent broadcastIntent=new Intent(context, typeof(class));` Or you could explicitly provide the package in an implicit intent. Please check the code in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183164/android-l-api-21-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be