# Application crashes when checking license in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-lvl

Since I have updated my phone to the Lollipop version of Android, my applications crash when they try to check the Google license (call to `checkAccess`). The error message is :

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service intent must be explicit: Intent {act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicenseService".

The code I use is :

```
myLicenseChecker=new LicenseChecker(myActivity,new ServerManagedPolicy(myActivity,new AESObfuscator(salt,myActivity.getPackageName(),identificationMatériel)),myPublicKey);
myResponseAnalyzer=new MyResponseAnalyzer();
myLicenseChecker.checkAccess(myResponseAnalyzer);
```

I have added the "com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" permission in the manifest file but it had no effect at all.

What could be the cause of the generated error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google In-App billing, IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit, after upgrading to Android L Dev Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480069/google-in-app-billing-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be-explicit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known Licensing Library bug.

Reported solution:

> As I put a few hours ago at  issue 1674 , another working solution is:
>
> ```
> Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(
>          new String(Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U=")));
>          serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
>
>          boolean bindResult = mContext
>                  .bindService(
>                    serviceIntent,
>                    this, // ServiceConnection.
>                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
> ```

[Bug report with solution above.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78505)