# API 23 (Android 6.0.1) InApp Billing: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I have been looking around and this seems to be a Android L related bug that was apparently solved solved using the code I already have.

When I try to call bindService I get:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must
>   be explicit: Intent {
>   act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BINL }

This is the piece of code that causes the crash:

```
    final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    activity.bindService(serviceIntent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

It only happens on Android 6.0.1 and my target in gradle in 23 and I can't seem to understand what's wrong with that on API 23...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IabHelper classes. Go to **startSetup** Method in **IabHelper**.java. add below code

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
            // service available to handle that Intent
            serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

            mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
        else {
            // no service available to handle that Intent
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onIabSetupFinished(
                        new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE,
                                "Billing service unavailable on device."));
            }
        }
```

This method will help you turn the implicit intent into the explicit form. Inspired from SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26318757/1446466
bindServiceConn() method is creating a service.

```
 * @param context
 * @param implicitIntent - The original implicit intent
 * @return Explicit Intent created from the implicit original intent
 */

public static Intent createExplicitFromImplicitIntent(Context context, Intent implicitIntent) {
    // Retrieve all services that can match the given intent
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = pm.queryIntentServices(implicitIntent, 0);

    // Make sure only one match was found
    if (resolveInfo == null || resolveInfo.size() != 1) {
        return null;
    }

    // Get component info and create ComponentName
    ResolveInfo serviceInfo = resolveInfo.get(0);
    String packageName = serviceInfo.serviceInfo.packageName;
    String className = serviceInfo.serviceInfo.name;
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(packageName, className);

    // Create a new intent. Use the old one for extras and such reuse
    Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(implicitIntent);

    // Set the component to be explicit
    explicitIntent.setComponent(component);

    return explicitIntent;
}



  protected void bindServiceConn() {
//call this method 
        Intent intent = createExplicitFromImplicitIntent(context.getApplicationContext(), new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"));
        context.bindService(intent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

protected void unbindServiceConn() {
    context.unbindService(mServiceConn);

    context=null;
}
```

Comment: In the original post we already see a call to `serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");`. I'm also seeing this error, and I have the `queryIntentServices` check as well as the explicit `setPackage()` call.  What's weird is that the error message mentions an intent ending with `BINL` instead of `BIND`.  I'm seeing this as well as the original poster.