# Android app licensing error class not found

Tags: android

I have worked through the example in the SDK and am now receiving the following error when trying to run the demo app.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rythmair.licenseverification.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rythmair.licenseverification-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Here is my full MainActivity

```
package com.rythmair.licenseverification;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.Policy;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String tag = "LICENSE: ";

    private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MY_KEY_REMOVED";

    // Generate your own 20 random bytes, and put them here.
    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {
            -46, 65, 30, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64, 51, 88, -95, -45, 77, -117, -36, -113, -11, 32, -64,
            89
    };

    private TextView mStatusText;
    private Button mCheckLicenseButton;

    private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
    private LicenseChecker mChecker;
    // A handler on the UI thread.
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(tag, "Just in onCreate method.");

        mStatusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        mCheckLicenseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_license_button);
        mCheckLicenseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doCheck();
            }
        });

        mHandler = new Handler();
        Log.i(tag, "Just set mHandler to new Handler.");
        // Try to use more data here. ANDROID_ID is a single point of attack.
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        // Library calls this when it's done.
        Log.i(tag, "Setting new mLicenseCheckerCallback");
        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();

        // Construct the LicenseChecker with a policy.
        Log.i(tag, "Setting mChecker variable.");
        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
                this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
                BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
        doCheck();
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final boolean bRetry = id == 1;
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.unlicensed_dialog_title)
                .setMessage(bRetry ? R.string.unlicensed_dialog_retry_body : R.string.unlicensed_dialog_body)
                .setPositiveButton(bRetry ? R.string.retry_button : R.string.buy_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    boolean mRetry = bRetry;
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if ( mRetry ) {
                            doCheck();
                        } else {
                            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                                    "http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                            startActivity(marketIntent);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.quit_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).create();
    }

    private void doCheck() {
        mCheckLicenseButton.setEnabled(false);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        mStatusText.setText(R.string.checking_license);
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }

    private void displayResult(final String result) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mStatusText.setText(result);
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                mCheckLicenseButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayDialog(final boolean showRetry) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                showDialog(showRetry ? 1 : 0);
                mCheckLicenseButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
        public void allow(int policyReason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // Should allow user access.
            displayResult(getString(R.string.allow));
        }

        public void dontAllow(int policyReason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            displayResult(getString(R.string.dont_allow));
            // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
            // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
            // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
            // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
            // restricted set of features.
            // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to Market.
            // If the reason for the lack of license is that the service is
            // unavailable or there is another problem, we display a
            // retry button on the dialog and a different message.
            displayDialog(policyReason == Policy.RETRY);
        }

        public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
            // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
            // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
            String result = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
            displayResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information in the below post got me past the current license issue I was experiencing.

[Google In-App billing, IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit, after upgrading to Android L Dev Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480069/google-in-app-billing-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be-explicit)

The license class in the Google API had to be updated / modified and the minSDK version had to be updated to 4 in the build file for the API.